# How to install Nuget Packages using ENVDTE.DTE

Tags: c#, nuget-package, envdte

I created one console application to create visual studio project pragmatically, here i am not able install Nuget packages, always 
**var componentModel = (IComponentModel)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SComponentModel));** **statement  returns null** values. for your reference i added my code below. Help me to resolve this issue.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //InstallNuGetPackages.InstallNuGet("");
            string ProjectName = "WebAPIProj";
            string SolutionName = "EmptyTemplate";
            System.Type type = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.11.0");
            Object obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);
            EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)obj;
            dte.MainWindow.Visible = true; // optional if you want to See VS doing its thing

            // create a new solution
            dte.Solution.Create("C:\\"+ SolutionName + "\\", SolutionName);
            var solution = dte.Solution;

            // create a C# WinForms app
            solution.AddFromTemplate(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache\CSharp\Web\1033\EmptyWebApplicationProject40\EmptyWebApplicationProject40.vstemplate",
                @"C:\NewSolution\"+ ProjectName, ProjectName);
            InstallNuGetPackages.InstallNuGet(dte);

            foreach (var p in dte.Solution.Projects)
            {
              InstallNuGetPackages.InstallNuGet((Project)p, "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi version1.1");
            }

            // save and quit
            dte.ExecuteCommand("File.SaveAll");
            dte.Quit();
        }
```

**Code to install Nuget Packages**

```
 public bool InstallNuGetPackage(Project project, string package)
    {
        bool installedPkg = true;
        try
        {
            var componentModel = (IComponentModel)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SComponentModel)); //Always this statement returns null
            IVsPackageInstallerServices installerServices = componentModel.GetService();
            if (!installerServices.IsPackageInstalled(project, package))
            {
                var installer = componentModel.GetService();
                installer.InstallPackage(null, project, package, (System.Version)null, false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            installedPkg = false;
        }
        return installedPkg;
    }
```

Comment: why are you doing this? have you looked to [Custom templates](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/tools/custom-templates.md) ?

Comment: i have to create many WebAPI project,  to reduce manual coding, i choosed this way.

Comment: If you can target dot net core 2 the CLI new command "[dotnet new webapi](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/tools/dotnet-new.md#net-core-2x-1)" creates just that.

Answer (score 0):

(Turned this into an answer for better readability and more room)

`created one console application` - you only have access to the `ServiceProvider` from Visual Studio if you run your code *inside* of it, i.e. from an [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2017) and/or [package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-an-extension-with-a-vspackage?view=vs-2017).

Running this from a console application cannot work. Visual Studio internally does a *lot* more setup for all the services and general environment than creating an instance of `DTE`.

To persue your route, although I'm not sure how feasible that is, invoke `nuget.exe` or [`NuGet.Core`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Core/) code to achieve similar.